# How do I use regular expression extractor in jmeter to extract a data from response data

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a get api response data as

```
{"result code":"OK",
"result Obj":{
     "List": [
       {
           "Id" :123,
           "Name" : "abc",
            "Ran" : 345
        },
        {
           "Id" :987,
           "Name" : "poi",
            "Ran" : 657
        }
      ]
}
}
```

I want to use regular expression extractor to extract the name variable data from response(there are n names as such not fixed) so I can use it in the beanshell assertion to compare it later on.

Can you please show how to use regular expression extractor to extract the name variable and id variable separately for this and how to use that variable later on.

I have tried giving "Name":"(.*?)" As reg expression and template $0$ but it's not working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/4017) therefore using Regular Expressions is not the best option to proceed, JMeter provides the following post-processors which are way more handy:

   - [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
   - [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/)

   For example [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) expression extracting names and ids would be something like:

   ```
    "result Obj".List[*].[Name,Id]
   ```

   [image]
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go with json extractor instead of regular expression extractor

1. json expression : $..Name
   match case is 1
2. Boundary extractor

left boundary::    "Name" : "

right boundary::   ",